# Why can not I use operator[] for std::unordered_map<std::pair<int,int>, int> but for same key-value pair of `std::map`?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, std, std-pair

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

std::unordered_map<std::pair<int,int>, int> mp;

int main()
{
    mp[make_pair(1, 2)]++;
}
```

When using the `[] operator`, I get this

```
error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, int>’ and ‘std::pair<int, int>’)
```

However, when doing the same with `std::map`, no error occurs. why?

How can I make it works with `std::unorderd_m`?

Comment: what is the version of c++ u r using?

Comment: I tried on both G++11 and G++17, same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when doing the same with `std::map`, no error occurs. why? And how can I
>   make it works with `std::unorderd_map` ?

Because they are simply different.

[`std::unorderd_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) the elements are placed according to the hash of its keys.

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Hash = std::hash<Key>,  
    class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator< std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class unordered_map;
```

whereas the [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) needs simply a  comparison function in order to sort the keys.

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class map;
```

The reason why your `std::map<std::pair<int,int>, int>` got compiled is, the [**`operator<`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) **is defined** for `std::pair` and `std::map` uses it to sort its keys, whereas the **hash function** for `std::pair` **has not been defined** and hence `std::unorderd_map` need one to keep elemets in its buckets. This you need to define.

For instance, you can define a custom hash function as follows:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>

struct CustomHash
{
  template <typename T, typename U>
  std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<T, U> &x) const
  {
    return std::hash<T>()(x.first) ^ std::hash<U>()(x.second);
  }
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::pair<int,int>, int, CustomHash> mp;
    mp[std::make_pair(1, 2)]++;
    return 0;
}
```

---

**PS**: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`is a bad coding practice. Why? see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) .

Comment: *If* template, I recommend having two template parameters such that you can calculate hashes for `std::pair<int, double>` or alike as well...

Comment: @Aconcagua True. let me edit with that. However, OP has only `int`s that means no templates needed at all.